# How to get the count of joined table (HABTM)

Tags: cakephp

Is there a way to get the count of items connected using HABTM?
For example I have tables Users and Tags. (and another one tags_users)

user model has the following:

```
public $hasAndBelongsToMany = array("Tags");
```

I can do simply **$this->User->find("all")** and I get the users and connected tags from the Tags table.
But instead of getting the tags I want to get the amount of the tags (count) for every user.

How to do this in cake?

Answer (score 1):

I found a simple solution:
In the User Model I just specify a virtualfield:

```
public  $virtualFields = array(
  'tag_count' => 'SELECT count(*) FROM tags_users WHERE user_id = User.id'
  );
```